# facebook og debugger can't parse port of string output from django request.build_absolute_uri

Tags: python, django, facebook-opengraph

Currently I'm rendering the `og:url` string from inside `view.py` which gets rendered in the template as follows:

```
# view.py
context = {
    'og_url' : request.build_absolute_uri()
}

# template.html
<meta property="og:url" content="{{ og_url }}" />
```

Then when I visit `http://beta.example.com:8000/`, I view the source... it correctly shows:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://beta.example.com:8000/" />
```

However when I run the Facebook OG Debugger, I get a 206 redirect to `http://beta.example.com` which is listed as the canonical url...  The only way I could get this working is if I copied the above output and pasted to replace the one in the template:

```
# template.html
<meta property="og:url" content="http://beta.example.com:8000/" />
```

After this, I tried hardcoding the string `http://beta.example.com:8000` in the view to be rendered in the template, which also worked:

```
# view.py
context = {
    'og_url' : "http://beta.example.com:8000/"
}

# template.html
<meta property="og:url" content="{{ og_url }}" />
```

This will correctly parse in Facebook OG... So I'm thinking this is a character set issue?  If so, who is to blame?  Django or Facebook?  Secondly what can I do in the mean time to properly ensure the output from Django will be parsed by Facebook?